# boolean union having problem when combining cubes with same height

Tags: modifiers

I tried to union 2 cubes , this supposed to be very easy task, but fail at some point. (cross object on the left) So i create union of two identical box/cube , i reposition the second cube so it cross each other and it works great. But in the right side, i tried to do the same thing but this time the cubes has different size but still have the same height so their top faces will be overlapped each other.

So i select the bigger cube, add boolean , pick the smaller cube, set to 'union' and set solver to 'bmesh' ( i tried carve and doesn't give a correct result). So they looks correct, but when i applied the boolean and go to edit mode, there're some overlapped interior faces which is not what i want, i can delete the faces but what is wrong ? how to fix this ?

Thanks

edit :
note:  to reproduce the error , the smaller cube has to have same height as the big cube , so both top faces have to overlap each other.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Select the large rectangular add boolean modifier. Select the object (small rectangular). Operation as union.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying , btw for those setup, i can make it work as well, because the smaller box has different height. Like i wrote in my post, the smaller box has to be the same exact height with the big box so the top and bottom faces will overlap each other. This time it won't work. or if you can make it work that way, pls update the video. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @andio plz attach your file so that i can solve the problem